# Extracting sentences from sequence of words and adding punctuation

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for a library or system that can try detect sentence boundaries and structure from a sequence of words. These words are from transcripts of presentations, included are things like filler words *um* and *uh*, as well as word repetitions. Here's an example:

`["hello", "everybody", "today", "we", "are", "going", "to", "um", "be", "discussing", "IO", "streams", "with", "IO", "streams", "we", ...]`

Google Cloud has the ability to add punctuation to the text output of its Speech-to-Text API using the `enableAutomaticPunctuation` option, however I have not found anything like this that takes text as input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at Text Mining libraries e.g. [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) or [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101). These libraries have inbuilt Sentence Tokenizers. Moreoever, you can also update the rules or list of abbreviations based on which text is converted into list of sentences.